# Linker Input File Unused

Tags: software-installation, symbolic-link, wget

I am trying to install wget from source and am receiving the following errors:

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/linux1/tmp/wget-1.18'
Making all in lib
make[2]: Entering directory '/linux1/tmp/wget-1.18/lib'
  GEN      alloca.h
  GEN      c++defs.h
  GEN      warn-on-use.h
  GEN      arg-nonnull.h
  GEN      arpa/inet.h
  GEN      configmake.h
  GEN      fcntl.h
  GEN      langinfo.h
  GEN      locale.h
  GEN      netdb.h
  GEN      signal.h
  GEN      spawn.h
  GEN      stddef.h
  GEN      stdio.h
  GEN      stdlib.h
  GEN      string.h
  GEN      strings.h
  GEN      sys/file.h
  GEN      sys/ioctl.h
  GEN      sys/select.h
  GEN      sys/socket.h
  GEN      sys/stat.h
  GEN      sys/time.h
  GEN      sys/types.h
  GEN      sys/uio.h
  GEN      sys/wait.h
  GEN      time.h
  GEN      unistd.h
  GEN      unitypes.h
  GEN      uniwidth.h
  GEN      wchar.h
  GEN      wctype.h
make  all-recursive
make[3]: Entering directory '/linux1/tmp/wget-1.18/lib'
make[4]: Entering directory '/linux1/tmp/wget-1.18/lib'
  CC       base32.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       binary-io.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       c-ctype.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       c-strcasecmp.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       c-strncasecmp.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       c-strcasestr.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       cloexec.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       md5.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       sha1.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       sha256.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       dirname.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       basename.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       dirname-lgpl.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       basename-lgpl.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       stripslash.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       exitfail.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       fatal-signal.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       fd-hook.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       fd-safer-flag.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       dup-safer-flag.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       gettime.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       localcharset.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       glthread/lock.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       mbchar.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       mbiter.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       pipe2.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       pipe2-safer.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       quotearg.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       sig-handler.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       sockets.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       spawn-pipe.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       stat-time.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       strnlen1.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       sys_socket.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       tempname.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       glthread/threadlib.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       timespec.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       tmpdir.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       unistd.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       dup-safer.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       fd-safer.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       pipe-safer.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       uniwidth/width.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       utimens.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       wait-process.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       wctype-h.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       xmalloc.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       xalloc-die.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       xsize.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       xstrndup.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       asnprintf.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       fcntl.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       futimens.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       getpass.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       ioctl.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       mktime.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       printf-args.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       printf-parse.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       strerror_r.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       vasnprintf.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  AR       libgnu.a
  GEN      charset.alias
  GEN      ref-add.sed
  GEN      ref-del.sed
make[4]: Leaving directory '/linux1/tmp/wget-1.18/lib'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/linux1/tmp/wget-1.18/lib'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/linux1/tmp/wget-1.18/lib'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory '/linux1/tmp/wget-1.18/src'
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory '/linux1/tmp/wget-1.18/src'
  CC       connect.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       convert.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       cookies.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       ftp.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       css_.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       css-url.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       ftp-basic.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       ftp-ls.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       hash.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       host.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       hsts.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       html-parse.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       html-url.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       http.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       init.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       log.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       main.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       netrc.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       progress.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       ptimer.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       recur.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       res.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       retr.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       spider.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       url.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       warc.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       utils.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       exits.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
if test -n ""; then cp "./build_info.c.in" .; fi
/usr/bin/perl "../build-aux/build_info.pl" \
    "../src/build_info.c"
if test -n ""; then rm -f build_info.c.in; fi
  CC       build_info.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
echo '/* version.c */' > version.c
echo '/* Autogenerated by Makefile - DO NOT EDIT */' >> version.c
echo '' >> version.c
echo '#include "version.h"' >> version.c
echo 'const char *version_string = "1.18";' >> version.c
echo 'const char *compilation_string = "'gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DSYSTEM_WGETRC=\"/linux1/etc/wgetrc\" -DLOCALEDIR=\"/linux1/share/locale\" -I.  -I../lib -I../lib   /linux1 -DHAVE_LIBGNUTLS -I/linux1/include -DNDEBUG '";' \
    | sed -e 's/[\\"]/\\&/g' -e 's/\\"/"/' -e 's/\\";$/";/' >> version.c
echo 'const char *link_string = "'gcc  /linux1 -DHAVE_LIBGNUTLS -I/linux1/include -DNDEBUG  \
  /linux1 -L/linux1/lib -lz   ftp-opie.o gnutls.o ../lib/libgnu.a'";' \
    | sed -e 's/[\\"]/\\&/g' -e 's/\\"/"/' -e 's/\\";$/";/' >> version.c
  CC       version.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       ftp-opie.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CC       gnutls.o
gcc: warning: /linux1: linker input file unused because linking not done
  CCLD     wget
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /linux1: File format not recognized
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /linux1: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [Makefile:1501: wget] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/linux1/tmp/wget-1.18/src'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:1400: all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/linux1/tmp/wget-1.18/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1408: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/linux1/tmp/wget-1.18'
make: *** [Makefile:1364: all] Error 2
```

Any help on how to proceed would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Using Ubuntu 14.04.05 on a VM in Windows 10 and attempting to install Wget-1.18 from source. I have gnutls-3.5.9 installed from source in my own `linux1/tmp/` directory

Comment: Where exactly in `linux/tmp` are the gnutls libraries and headers - what is the directory structure? How did you specify that to the configure script? BTW please post terminal output as text rather than images.

Comment: re the text output, will do thanks. As for the gnutls libraries and headers... they are in `/linux1/tmp/gnutls-3.5.9/lib`

Comment: Also, (in the comments below) note the flags I included on the ./configure in order to get that to work... I'm guessing that's part of the problem

Comment: In place of setting `GNUTLS_CFLAGS` and `GNUTLS_LIBS` on the `./configure` command line, try `--with-libgnutls-prefix=/linux1/tmp/gnutls-3.5.9`

Comment: Oooh!! That worked . . . kinda. Now it's throwing an SSL error but my guess is I need to link the version of openssl that I have in `/linux1` the same way. It seems like in your comments you're helping me solve the problems I had here: [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/900257/how-to-determine-linking-programs)

Comment: It's often informative to run `./configure --help` to get a list of the optional component flags for the particular source package

Answer (score 0):

You need to install libgnutls-dev

```
sudo apt-get install libgnutls-dev
```

emphasis on the DEV part :)

Comment: Not working still, unfortunately. I have gnutls installed, but I'm trying to compile wget into my own folder: `/linux1`; when I do `./configure --prefix="/linux1" --exec-prefix="/linux1"` I get stopped at an error that it cannot find GNUTLS, so I set the following:

`./configure --prefix="/linux1" --exec-prefix="/linux1" GNUTLS_CFLAGS=/linux1 GNUTLS_LIBS=/linux1`

That finds GNUTLS, and allows the configure to finish; but, I get the OP error when I run `make`

Comment: You installed libginutls-dev? you need the dev tools.

Comment: With apt-get I did... but, perhaps I need to do that from source too. Or find a way to tell apt-get that I want everything installed in my `/linux1` directory. Thanks for the help, I will do some searching...

Comment: @AntonRasmussen I'm confused - please clarify whether you want to use the `apt-get` versions of the gnutls libraries, or the ones you installed manually in `/linux1/tmp`

Comment: @steeldriver ... I'm required to install wget from source in `/linux1`. But, not required to install gnutls libraries from source... but, in an effort to fix the problem I installed gnutls 3.5.9 from source in `/linux1` and figured it would be best to use that version to build wget since I am trying to use the builds in `/linux1` as dependencies for other builds as much as possible--if need be. For example, I am using my own gcc built in `/linux1`to build everything instead of the gcc that I apt-get installed with build essential (which I, of course, had to use to build the gcc in `/linux1`).

Comment: @AntonRasmussen ah... OK. Good luck with that ;)